# Python & sql server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

What is the best way to access sql server from python is it DB-API ?
Also could someone provide a such code using the DB-API how to connect to sql server from python and excute query ?

Answer (score 15):

See [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) - [Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) implementation. Works great.

Additionally you can use it with other databases. If using with SQL Server 2008, make sure you use Native Driver if you need to support new `DATE` data types.

Comment: I have a data conversion project that uses pyodbc with SQL Server, and it works great.

Answer (score 6):

See [pymssql](http://pymssql.org/) It is a DB-API module for MS Sql Server and would be the most pythonic way. The documentation includes examples.

If on a Windows OS you could also use [OLEDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722784(VS.85).aspx) through COM which will not require any thing else to be installed on the client.

Also if you use Iron Python you can use the .Net APIs

Comment: @gt6989b that is the website in the answer (when you commented)

Comment: @Mark you are right, sorry, i guess i clicked something different

Answer (score 4):

```
Also could someone provide a such code using the DB-API 
how to connect to sql server from python and excute query ?
```

[This hello world snippet](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/wiki/A_HelloWorld_sample_to_access_mssql_with_python) pretty much shows you the common way how to connect with SQL server in Python with an DBI 2.0 database interface module.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of pypyodbc

Answer (score 1):

ODBC + freetds + a python wrapper library for ODBC.