# Connecting to SQL Server instance with Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Good morning everyone,

I have a problem connecting to a SQL instance with python using mysql connector.
The complete server adress / host name looks like "MSQL\INST1" and I can connect to it through Excel without any problem.

If I try
`mysql.connector.connect(host="MSQL\INST1", user=" Report", passwd="123", db="abc")`
I get: 
MySQLInterfaceError: Unknown MySQL server host 'MSQL\INST1' (11)

And if I try it without the instance:
`mysql.connector.connect(host="MSQL", user=" Report", passwd="123", db="abc")`
I get: 
MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'MSQL' (10061)

Do I miss something? In every tutorial I found the host name is without any instance...

Best regards,
Joachim

Comment: Wait, are you trying to connect to [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql-server/sql-server-2016) or to [MySql](https://www.mysql.com/fr/)?

Comment: I want to connect to a MS SQL Server. I think I read yesterday that this should work with the mysql connector. But now it looks like I have to use another python module?

Comment: Yeah, MySql and Sql Server are two different database systems.

Comment: However, take a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314178/python-sql-server

Comment: Thanks! I tried pyodbc, but didn't get it to work. Then I tried pymssql and it worked right from the beginning. :-)